# Using Firestore, can you update and add to a sub-collection using a single update call?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I see that there is an example that calls `update()` and updates nested fields with firestore.  Can you do a similar thing that does an update and adds to a subcollection instead?

e.g. we change this example from favorites being an object hash to a subcollection

```
var frankDocRef = db.collection("users").doc("frank");
frankDocRef.set({
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", subject: "recess" },
    age: 12
});
```

to

```
frankDocRef.set({
    name: "Frank",
    favorites.add({ food: "Pizza"}), // I know this is probably the wrong syntax
    age: 12
});
```

Would I create a batched write or a transaction because it goes across a single document and a sub-collection document separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't offer an API to update multiple documents (no matter where they live) in a single call to set() or update() on a document reference.

You should do a [batch write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) instead if you want to update multiple documents atomically.  You only need a transaction if you need to read the value of a document before updating it (for doing things like incrementing a count).